# C# list to JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can i save my list of objects in json file?
It's my code:

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/settings.conf"));
            dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

City city = svm.City;
            jsonObj["city"]["name"] = city.Name;
            jsonObj["city"]["latitude"] = city.Latitude;
            jsonObj["city"]["longitude"] = city.Longitude;
            jsonObj["city"]["id"] = city.ID;
List<Social> bottomSocial = svm.BottomSocials;
            jsonObj["bottomSocial"] = bottomSocial;


            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/settings.conf"), output);
```

It works great for City, but don't works for bottomSocial.

Comment: Can you share the json object and your Social class object

Comment: I resolve this problem, simply: JToken.FromObject(bottomSocial)